# Lyndon-Schützenberger for torsion-free hyperbolic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Given a torsion-free hyperbolic group $G$, does there exist a number $n(G)$ such that for any $x,y,z\in G$, $x^n y^n z^n =1$ implies that $x$, $y$, and $z$ commute pairwise?

Some musings/questions...
When $G$ is free, the result is true for $n=2$.

Clearly, this does not generalize to hyperbolic groups (e.g. non-orientable surface groups of genus 3).

Somewhat related: given any 3 non-commuting elements $x,y,z\in G$ there is a number $n(x,y,z)$ such that $\langle x^n, y^n , z^n \rangle $ is free.  Is this true??..definitely in case of two elements (Gromov).

Comment: for the last question, two non-commuting elements of infinite order in a discrete hyperbolic group have disjoint ends (the ends of a hyperbolic isometry are the two fixed ends). So Gromov's argument of freeness (for some suitable powers) works with no change.

Comment: PS: for these question we need the hyperbolic group to have a trivial finite radical (the finite radical $W(G)$ is the largest finite normal subgroup, which in a discrete hyperbolic group $G$ does exist). Otherwise the last question has stupid counterexamples (take semidirect products $M\rtimes F$ with $M$ finite and $F$ free). Or alternatively replace everywhere "commute" by "commute modulo $W(G)$".

Comment: Yves, the $G$ is assumed torsion-free....

Comment: but thanks for confirming the answer to the second question. the argument with disjoint ends works.

Comment: ah ok you're right. But anyway for a discrete hyperbolic group, "torsion-free" is a very strong hypothesis while "trivial finite radical" is a very weak hypothesis (as we can always boil down to it by modding out).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second statement is true if $x,y,z$ are not torsion as proved by Arzhantseva and, independently, by Kapovich and Weidmann (see Arzhantseva, Goulnara N.
A dichotomy for finitely generated subgroups of word hyperbolic groups.  Topological and asymptotic aspects of group theory, 1–10, 
Contemp. Math., 394, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2006 and Kapovich, Ilya; Weidmann, Richard
Nielsen methods and groups acting on hyperbolic spaces. 
Geom. Dedicata 98 (2003), 95–121. This also implies the first statement (about the equation $x^ny^nz^n=1$) in the torsion-free case.

Comment: It's not clear why the positive answer to the 2nd question implies a positive question to the first, since in the second statement $n$ depends on $(x,y,z)$ and in the first statement there is a single $n(G)$. Unless the given references give $n(x,y,z)$ independent of $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: $n(x,y,z)$ depends only on $\delta$, the hyperbolicity constant. It is something like $12\delta$. 

Comment: Mark, thanks for the answer. I'm familiar with that result (i.e. an alternative that either a given f.g. subgroup of $G$ is free or a tuple of it's generator is Nielsen equivalent to a tuple of "short" elements). 
However, like Yves, I fail to see how it implies the answer to the first question. 


Comment: Let $G$ be torsion-free. Take any three pairwise non-commuting elements $x,y,z$. Then $x^n,y^n,z^n$ are not equivalent to short elements where $n=n(\delta)$ does not depend on $x,y,z$ (this is a standard hyperbolic argument). Then $x^n,y^n,z^n$ freely generate free subgroup. Hence if $x^{2n}y^{2n}z^{2n}=1$, then $x^{n}, y^n, z^n$ pairwise commute, a contradiction (the centralizer of an element in a torsion-free hyperbolic group is cyclic, so if $x,y$ do not commute, no powers of $x,y$ commute either).

Comment: Mark, your argument also implies that for the classical fact (Gromov) about two non-commuting elements $g,h\in G$ ($G$ is torsion-free), the power $n$ for which $ < g^n , h^n > $ generate a free subgroup can be chosen as not depending on those elements? I was not aware of that. thanks for clarifying your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is no difficult to prove using asymptotic cones for example.